# How do I look up a MavenProject?

Tags: maven-2, maven

How do I programmatically construct a MavenProject instance (not the current project) given its groupId, artifactId, version, etc?

**UPDATE**: I'm trying to create a patch for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-322. I believe the maven-dependency-plugin depends on Maven 2.x so I can't use any Maven 3.x APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you would go about doing this depends on whether you want to construct the project from an artifact in your local repository or from a pom file on your hard drive. Either way, you'll need to get a `ProjectBuilder`, which you can do like so in a Mojo:

```
/** @component role = "org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuilder" */
protected ProjectBuilder m_projectBuilder;
```

If you want to build from an artifact in your local repo, you'll also need:

```
/** @parameter expression="${localRepository}" */
protected ArtifactRepository m_localRepository;
```

Once you have that, you can construct a `MavenProject` from an artifact from your local repository:

```
  //Construct the artifact representation
Artifact artifact = 
    new DefaultArtifact(groupId,artifactId,version,scope,type,classifier,new DefaultArtifactHandler());
  //Resolve it against the local repository
artifact = m_localRepository.find(artifact);
  //Create a project building request
ProjectBuildingRequest request = new DefaultProjectBuildingRequest();
  //Build the project and get the result
MavenProject project = m_projectBuilder.build(artifact,request).getProject();
```

Or from a pom file:

```
File pomFile = new File("path/to/pom.xml");
ProjectBuildingRequest request = new DefaultProjectBuildingRequest();
MavenProject project = m_projectBuilder.build(pomFile,request).getProject();
```

Comment: I've sorry, I should have mentioned: I'm trying to build a patch for maven-dependency-plugin which depends on Maven 2.x. I can't use the Maven 3.x APIs you mention above.

Comment: In that case you will likely need to make use of the MavenProjectBuilder class, the 2.x equivalent of the 3.x ProjectBuilder. You should be able to get an instance of that using @component role="org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectBuilder", most of the other classes should either be present in the 2.x api or have a close approximate.